# Add postId to comments with autoform in Meteor

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, meteor-autoform

How can I link add `postId` to comments when using `meteor-autoform`?

I have tried

```
AutoForm.hooks({
  insertCommentForm: {
    formToDoc: function(doc) {
      doc.postId = this.formAttributes.parentContext._id;
      return doc;
    },
  }
});
```

and

```
AutoForm.hooks({
  insertCommentForm: {
    formToDoc: function(doc) {
      doc.postId = Template.parentData(1)._id;
      return doc;
    },
  }
});
```

and

```
AutoForm.hooks({
  insertCommentForm: {
    before: {
      method: function(doc) {
        doc.postId = this.formAttributes.parentContext._id;
        return doc;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

and

```
AutoForm.hooks({
  insertCommentForm: {
    before: {
      method: function(doc) {
        doc.postId = Template.parentData(1)._id;
        return doc;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

but `postId` is undefined no matter what I do.

## Edit

I use it like this:

```
<template name="comment">
  <div>
    <h1>{{_id}} {{title}}</h1>
    {{#if currentUser}}
      {{> quickForm collection="Comments" id="insertCommentForm" type="insert"}}
    {{/if}}
    ....
```

so `_id` should be accessible.

## Edit 2

Now I have tried

```
before: {
  insert: function(doc, template) {
    doc.postId = Template.instance().post._id;
    console.log(doc);
    return doc;
  }
},
```

and in the template I use

```
{{> quickForm collection="Comments" id="insertCommentForm" type="insert" post=this template="bootstrap3-inline" label-class="sr-only"}}
```

but post is `undefined` so I get the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined`.

Comment: Are you able to log/access the value of _id on your "parent Template" if you try it there? This will make sure, that your attribute _id is available as expected.

Comment: I have updated my question. The variable `_id` is accessible so I guess I should be able to load it in the autoform hook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead using your

{{> quickForm collection="Comments" id="insertCommentForm" type="insert"}}

just try

{{> quickForm collection="Comments" id="insertCommentForm" type="insert" postId=_id}}

and then try to access this value inside the helper via

Template.instance().data.postId

---

You also can send the whole post object to the sub-template like

{{> quickForm collection="Comments" id="insertCommentForm" type="insert" post=this}}

and then have full access to that collection document via

(e.g.)

Template.instance().data.post._id

---

This is a small sample for accessing data through templates

http://meteorpad.com/pad/Ke9DJnbvtsqjSHJy2/SimpleDataGivenThroughTemplates

Comment: Excuse me, I missed the data property - you have to use Template.instance().data. ... Please see updated answer.